# What kind of math should I learn before I tackle policy search PEGASUS research paper by Andrew Ng?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, artificial-intelligence

I provided the link below

https://ai.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/uai00-pegasus.pdf

the paper was referenced in the AI: Modern Approach book, and I would like to dive in depth into it. But my math is limited as I am a CS major, not a math major. Can any math gurus point me to what math I should prep up before I start to jump into it?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

I took a very quick look at the paper. With limited math you have a lot of work to do catching up. YOu will need linear algebra (more than what's in most standard one semester courses), probability theory and some statistics, some discrete mathematics - and the courage to master complex mathematical structures so you can begin to understand how they work and what they model. It looks as if these authors are generalizing other people's complicated models, so you may well have to look through those papers too.

You might try to read it and work backwards studying things you don't understand as you come to them rather than starting with formal courses in the background material.